# Undefined hw_who()?

Tags: php

Hi i found this function [**hw_who()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hw-who.php) which says to Gets the list of currently logged in users.

however when i want to use it like that:

```
  print_r(hw_who());
```

i get this error message

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function hw_who() in ...
```

I have looked every where but it seems no post or how to use it.

anyhelp thanks !

EDIT:

my php version is : **PHP Version 5.4.26**

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: Do you have [HyperWave](http://www.php.net/manual/en/hw.setup.php) installed and enabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: i edited my php version.

Comment: Did you install the extentsion?
This extension is considered unmaintained and dead. However, the source code for this extension is still available within PECL SVN here: » http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/hyperwave.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to work with php 4?

Comment: @JohnConde there is no hyperwave in php.ini , i have looked for name `hyperwave` and nothing is there. did it have other name ?

Comment: So, I am not sure that you are understanding that this function is exposed as part of a commercial library called HyperWave.  If you don't have this extension installed in PHP (which you likely would not by default), you don't have this function available to you.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/hw.installation.php):

> This extension is considered unmaintained and dead. However, the
>   source code for this extension is still available within PECL SVN
>   here: » http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/hyperwave.
>
> This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no
>   longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 5.0.0

So either you've installed it incorrectly via PECL, or you just haven't considered that.

My advice: Tackle your issue at hand differently.

Comment: how to install it? i have checked php.ini and nothing is there. should i ask my host ?

Comment: You can ask your host, but since this extension is unmaintained, I doubt they install it for you. My advice still stands: Tackle your issue at hand differently. There must be a different, maybe better way to count your logged in users.

Comment: Hmm it seems i will close door on that function and try something else. ok thanks for your effort.